# Is there a way I can ditch the copies of type definitions I made to make them globally available?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

So I'm very new to typescript and I know very little about it. But with a lot of pain and effort I was able to get it to work with VueJS.

[Here's the template that I built.](https://github.com/Evertt/vue-ts-template)

One of the things I desperately wanted and which took me a long time to accomplish is to make it so that I don't need to import Vue or any type decorators like `Component` in every freaking component that I make. As you can see in [this particular vue file](https://github.com/Evertt/vue-ts-template/blob/master/src/components/Hello.vue) I'm extending Vue and using many different type decorators and yet I don't have to import them. That is just so nice on the eyes for me.

However, the way I accomplished that isn't all that beautiful. I basically just copied the type definitions of all those things into [this folder](https://github.com/Evertt/vue-ts-template/tree/master/types). This sucks, because as soon as any of those packages change their type definitions, my template starts to break down.

However, I found that if I tried to simply import those type definitions (I tried a number of ways) then they aren't globally available in all my `.vue` files.

I'd like to know, is it possible to simply import those type definitions in one place and make them available to all my `.vue` files? If so, can anybody tell me how to do it? If this works out I'll be so happy. I really worked for days on getting this to work as much as I did.

Comment: I'm not a Vue expert (playing around for a week now) but what comes to my mind is storing data as an array in a importable js, then import those data to your root Vue component's data and then access it in any child component you wish by `this.$root.$data.yourDefinitinos` (or something like that). Tell me what you think, I can post full answer if you wish

Comment: I'm guessing that does something completely different from what I want. I don't want to access any data. I just want to be able to use type decorators without having the import them. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I misunderstood you.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use typescript, but would you be able to do this by writing a [plugin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)?

Comment: Pretty sure I wouldn't, because this is more related to typescript than it is to vuejs.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your types in the `global` scope:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

declare global {
  const VueComponent: typeof Component
  class VueClass extends Vue {}
}

// From another file
@VueComponent({
  props: {
    propMessage: String
  }
})
export default class App extends VueClass {

}
```